# CTE query taking forever to load

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, common-table-expression

I am creating a MLM application with laravel and using `https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list`
My table is very simple having below:

```
Schema::create('user_relations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id')->primary();
            $table->integer('parent_id');
            $table->integer('status')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

and I am running Query like this:

```
$total = \App\User_relation::find($parent_id);

if ($total)
    return $total->descendants()->count();
return 0;
```

User_relation model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Staudenmeir\LaravelAdjacencyList\Eloquent\HasRecursiveRelationships;

class User_relation extends Model
{
    use HasRecursiveRelationships;
}
```

It works fine upto 13000 records, but I am testing with 36000 records with same code and it loads forever. What can be the issue and how can I solve it? when tested with 13000 records it took 186 seconds.

Comment: Can you also show the "User_relation" model ?

Comment: what works fine up to 13000 records? is that second code block in a loop?

Comment: @lagbox I am not getting the point

Comment: Does `parent_id` have an index?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir no it doesn't

Comment: Try adding an index to the column. This typically improves performance a lot.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir allright